# Passing values from a controller to a GSP - to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, groovy

When we need to pass some values from `Controller` to a `view` we use to send it through `model`.

In Controller

```
render(view : "projectView", model:[p:project]);
```

In GSP

```
<html>
   <head>Test</head>
   <body>${p}</body>
</html>
```

But I'd to grab the value of `${p}` and make use of it in a JavaScript method. How can I do that?

```
function messageKeyPress(field, event) {
   var theCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : 
                    event.which ? event.which : 
                    event.charCode;
   var message = $('#messageBox').val();
   if (theCode == 13) {
      var Person = ${p}
   }                            
}
```

`Firefox` complains that there's a syntax error, and doesn't take the value `${p}`. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Where is this javascript method defined? As part of your gsp or in separate *.js file?

Comment: As part of the GSP, and i am also expecting a solution where the JS is part of the GSP.

Comment: And what's the value of `p`?

Comment: Its the `id`. ex: 12. a number

Comment: So could you show source of generated page? Especially this part with js script.

Comment: @PawełPiecyk It only displays `var Person =`. It has ignored the `${p}` part of it. This only takes place in Firefox. Google chrome works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose `${p}` in quotes, like `"${p}"`, if it is not a String in JSON format.

Comment: What do you mean in JASON format. Can you show me an example. Because i want to show an `id` which is a number.

Comment: Since it is a number, forget what I said about JSON. I made a similar test here, with `p` being a number and exactly the same JS code of yours, and it worked nicely. I am using Firefox 30 on Ubuntu 14.04.