# How to pass a value directly from a controller to a javascript file in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

Would like to pass directly from the controller to a JavaScript file.

TestControler.groovy

```
def list() {
    render (view: "list", model:[theId: theId])
}
```

Test.js

```
function test() {
   // do smth with theId
}
```

Found solution have the rendered gsp in the middle, i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702043/passing-values-from-a-controller-to-a-gsp-to-a-javascript-function), but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid that including using hidden fields or having in the gsp file a javascript code snippet such as:

```
<g:javascript>
   function test(${theId}) {
       // do smth with theId
   }
</g:javascript>
```

Comment: The JavaScript file is on the users computer, running in their browser. Your controller is running on your server. There is a large distance between them. Hence no

Comment: Was wondering if there is convention thing also for .js files similar to what is now implemented in Grails: TestController -> Test Views (that have .gsp files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be anything that covers what you're looking for. The best approach that I have seen, and have used myself, is to use hidden fields in the gsp/html, and retrieve those values from javascript on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue this is how I solved it.

say you have this controller:

```
def list() {
    render (view: "list", model:[theId: theId])
}
```

Then on your view( list.gsp)

```
<g:javascript>
   var theId = ${theId}
</g:javascript>
```

Then your function on the external file can do anything with variable `theId` because it global variable.

```
function test() {
   // do smth with theId
}
```

Personally I was having a complex json object so instead of coding the json into html and prasing it back to json when needed on the client side, I just put it as js json variable from my gsp and then I can do whatever I want from the client side