# How to pass or use variable from GSP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have below line in my grails gsp file.

```
    <div class="pagination">
        <g:paginate total="${lotCount ?: 0}" />
    </div>
```

I want to pass ***lotCount*** value to one of my javascript named area-switcher.js file to further use it. How can I do this?

I tried to refer one suggestion from [How to pass a value directly from a controller to a javascript file in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016425/how-to-pass-a-value-directly-from-a-controller-to-a-javascript-file-in-grails)
where I do below in my gsp

```
<g:javascript> var theId = ${lotCount} </g:javascript>
```

and try below in my js file for testing

```
alert(theId);
```

but it doesn't work.
Got error like ReferenceError: theId is not defined.
Please help.

Comment: start by putting speech marks around the id call so `var theId = "${lotCount}";`

Comment: @vahid I still have the same error as theId is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Use a hiddenField:

```
<g:hiddenField name="lotCount" value="${lotCount}" />

<div class="pagination">
    <g:paginate total="${lotCount ?: 0}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work.

Just ensure that in source of generated html page line

```
<g:javascript> var theId = ${lotCount} </g:javascript>
```

is placed **before** line which includes area-switcher.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="area-switcher.js">
```

Besides that, there are two more options to pass some value from .gsp to javascript file (examples use jQuery):

1. By using of data attribute. For example,

gsp (here div, span, input, other tags could be used):

```
<div id="countElem" data-count="${count}">
```

js(jQuery used here):

```
var count = $("#countElem").data('count');
```

2. As was mentioned in another comments, by using of hidden field:

gsp:

```
<g:hiddenField name="countElem" data-count="${count}"/>
```

js(jQuery used here):

```
// hidden field will have name and id equals to countElem
var count =  $("#countElem").val();
```